# Android Intents, questions about setClass()

Tags: android

I just started learning android programming and while working through the android Tab Layout tutorial I noticed they created a new Intent with the following code.

```
// Create an Intent to launch an Activity for the tab (to be reused)
intent = new Intent().setClass(this, ArtistsActivity.class);
```

Up until now, all the books I've read have created a new intent using

```
intent = new Intent(this, ArtistActivity.class);
```

and was wondering if there is a difference between the two lines of code.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

They are equivalent.

Based on the comment from the tutorial...

```
// Create an Intent to launch an Activity for the tab (to be reused)
```

It seems they just use the `.setClass()` method instead of the `Constructor` that takes a class to be more explicit as the Intent item created there will be reused and `.setClass()` will probably be called on it again.

Comment: Ahh, I thought they did the same thing. I'm still pretty new to programming and sometimes find it hard to understand the API documentation so I just needed confirmation. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can use `.setClass` when the same Intent may have two different class depending on some condition. Here's an exemple :

```
 Intent resultIntent = new Intent();

  if (condition) {
     resultIntent.setClass(getApplicationContext(), XXXX.class);
                startActivity(resultIntent);
  }else {
     resultIntent.setClass(getApplicationContext(), YYYY.class);
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

There's no practical difference. There is just a difference on how it's being done. One is using the constructor, while the other one a setter. But the end result is exactly the same. See the [documentation.](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#setClass%28android.content.Context,%20java.lang.Class%3C?%3E%29)