# Second activity not showing on real phone

Tags: android, kotlin

My app works absolutely fine on the emulator. but when i get it to a real phone (tried on multiple: one plus 7t pro running android 10, Samsung M20 running android 10), the second activity doesnt launch at all.

I tried a simple app that just launches a second activity & nothing happens even in this. Im out of ideas on what to do!

Here is my main activity:

```
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.view.View
import android.widget.TextView

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
    }

    fun btnClick(view: View){
        intent.setClass(this,ViewExpenseList::class.java)
        intent.putExtra("Text",findViewById<TextView>(R.id.helloWorld).text.toString())
        startActivityForResult(intent,1)
    }
}
```

activity xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/helloWorld"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Hello World!"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="159dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="21dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="164dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="286dp"
        android:onClick="btnClick"
        android:text="Button"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/helloWorld" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

My second activity:

```
package com.anand.expensetracker

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.widget.TextView

class ViewExpenseList : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_view_expense_list)

        findViewById<TextView>(R.id.textView).text=intent.getStringExtra("Text") +"asdfghj"
    }
}
```

My android manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.anand.expensetracker"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="@string/versionName">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".ViewExpenseList"></activity>
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try change

```
intent.setClass(this,ViewExpenseList::class.java)
```

to

```
val intent = Intent(this, ViewExpenseList::class.java)
```

Comment: Thanks. This worked. Just curious, why does this work, while setClass doesn't?

Comment: maybe try this `intent.setClass(this@MainActivity, ViewExpenseList::class.java)`

Answer (score 0):

Do it like this below

```
fun btnClick(view: View){
        //Get text from view
        val myText = helloWorld.text.toString()
        //Launch ViewExpenseList Activity
        val intent = Intent(this,ViewExpenseList::class.java)
        intent.putExtra("Text",myText)
        startActivity(intent)
    }
```

Comment: Thanks. This worked. Just curious, why does this work, while setClass doesn't?

Comment: Check it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6256413/android-intents-questions-about-setclass)